# Change the color of the iOS 7 status bar in Safari and Chrome

Tags: iphone, mobile, mobile-safari, ios7, mobile-website

I want to change the color of the iOS 7 status bar in Safari and Chrome. I'm working on a mobile web app and would like it to feel native and right now, I just get a white status bar.

[image: What I want to change]

Answer (score 13):

I'm using this while ios has the bug mentioned in other answers.

First I set the statusbar with this:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

For me, that sets the text white and background transparent. It also floats over my content.

Then I have following css:

```
body{
    background:#dddddd;
}
body:before{
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    height:20px;
    top: 0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    position:-webkit-sticky;
    position:sticky;
}
```

With this approach I have a dark background on my statusbar with some transparency.

I have not tested this with ios6 and it will probably break once Apple fixes the bug. Also it looks a bit off when scrolling to the top and the bounce effect moves the background from below the statusbar.

Still, it's quite easy fix for now and mostly CSS.

Comment: You can play around with different colors, I just posted the ones I'm currently using. Try changing the body background color to your liking, also try changing the rgba color for the statusbar.

Answer (score 7):

#### Update 3

`minimal-ui` was removed in iOS 8 :( More info here:
[iOS 8 removed "minimal-ui" viewport property, are there other "soft fullscreen" solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889100/ios-8-removed-minimal-ui-viewport-property-are-there-other-soft-fullscreen)

#### Update 2

A different bug now appears in iOS 7.1. No matter what `content` is set to, and regardless of page's `background-color`, the status bar is always translucent when user added the web app to home screen. See demo [here](http://shan.io/ios-web-app-tester).

Note that iOS 7.1 introduced a new tag called `minimal-ui`, which helps to hide browser chrome in Mobile Safari, but does nothing when added to home screen. More detail [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.1/).

#### Update

Still a bug in 7.0.4.

---

There appears to be a bug as of iOS 7.0.3.

Not having `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style">` defined or defining it as `content="default"` = black background with black text.

`content="black"` = black background with white text.

`content="black-translucent"` = black background with white text if canvas background isn't pure white (`FFF`). Or translucent background with black text if background is white.

Any other `content` value such as `white` doesn't work and `default` behavior is exhibited.

[image]

Confirmed by this reference:
http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

Comment: Upvoting for highlighting the behavior of "black-translucent". Kind of frustrating since the light gray header background color is common now. Trying to trick it into thinking the background is white when it's actually light gray but not having much luck.

Answer (score 5):

I've been looking for a way to do the same thing. The only options I've seen so far involve using one of these three meta tag's in the  of your html document.

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">`

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">`
This makes the status bar black and pushes the content below the status bar.

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">`
This makes the content go behind the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can affect the tint of the top bar in safari by changing the body's background color

```
body {
  background-color: blue; /* for the tint */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, green 0%, green 100%); /* for the body */
}
```

via http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

Comment: Sorry, but this is just incorrect. This only *works* because of safari's transparency, whereas the correct way to do it is with meta tags.